# Error on update-database in EF 6 Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I can't manage that situation on my own and I'm not capable of finding a solution on the web so I ask there, hope that someone has faced this problem yet.
I have a more than one year project, this week I start to put in Data Annotation everything can stay there because the code of the context class was unreadable. I don't know if it is the starting of my problem, but after that (and an update on the DB code) I wasn't able to create a new migration, I've tried to go back and ahead with the update-database command, if I go back everything is fine, but if I go ahead it works but give me this error:

```
PM> Update-Database -TargetMigration:Profili
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [202002031249206_Profili].
Applying explicit migration: 202002031249206_Profili.
System.InvalidOperationException: La sequenza contiene più elementi corrispondenti
   in System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.<>c__DisplayClass260.<FindAlteredColumns>b__257(<>f__AnonymousType2d`2 <>h__TransparentIdentifier252)
   in System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   in System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   in System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   in System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(ModelMetadata source, ModelMetadata target, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, Lazy`1 modificationCommandTreeGenerator, MigrationSqlGenerator migrationSqlGenerator, String sourceModelVersion, String targetModelVersion)
   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument model, DbMigration lastMigration)
   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClasse.<Update>b__d()
   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
La sequenza contiene più elementi corrispondenti
PM>
```

I tried to apply one migration at a time on a new and empty DB, same error, on a migration created one year ago, tried to eliminate the first migration that gives this error, because it creates a table that I don't use, I've removed this one but still give this error on the next one, so I tried to remove the last one that won't give the error, it made 2 columns alter, nothing to do, same error when I go ahead.

It seems to make a SingleOrDefault after he has done the update, but I don't know what he does. The same function was called before the Add-Migration command, so the migration doesn't create.

What can I try?

EDIT:
@Donal this is the code of the first migration that give me this problem:

```
namespace EF_Produser.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    
    public partial class Profili : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("PRODUSER.SYS_ABPRF_PROFILI", "ABPRF_FL_LINGUA", c => c.Int());
            AddColumn("PRODUSER.SYS_ABPRF_PROFILI", "ABPRF_LINGUA_UI", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 25));
            AddColumn("PRODUSER.SYS_ABPRF_PROFILI", "ABPRF_LINGUA_CONT", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 25));
            AddColumn("PRODUSER.SYS_ABPRF_PROFILI", "ABPRF_FL_CATART", c => c.Int());
            AddColumn("PRODUSER.SYS_ABPRF_PROFILI", "ABPRF_FL_ANAG", c => c.Int());
        }
        
        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("PRODUSER.SYS_ABPRF_PROFILI", "ABPRF_FL_ANAG");
            DropColumn("PRODUSER.SYS_ABPRF_PROFILI", "ABPRF_FL_CATART");
            DropColumn("PRODUSER.SYS_ABPRF_PROFILI", "ABPRF_LINGUA_CONT");
            DropColumn("PRODUSER.SYS_ABPRF_PROFILI", "ABPRF_LINGUA_UI");
            DropColumn("PRODUSER.SYS_ABPRF_PROFILI", "ABPRF_FL_LINGUA");
        }
    }
}
```

nothing strange, is not? For unique key... Every file start with the timestamp, if it is so it is ok.

Comment: Hi Simona, this may happen when there are duplicate columns with same or different casing. Can you add some code which gives better understanding?

Comment: Column with the same name, dbset that has the same name. entity with a table name.

Comment: can you post the code of the migration that is causing the issue? Does the migration have a unique key defined?

Comment: @NandanAcharya, I don't know what to show to you, I've 106 table on my db, I need somehow a clue on where to search. Anywhere, I don't think it may be a case problem, because I write all the table and field name in upper case, a duplicate in this case had to be catched by the c# compiler

Comment: @Donal I'll edit my question

Comment: @SimonaDiIenno Can you check the PRODUSER.SYS_ABPRF_PROFILI table to see if it already has those columns? If the columns already exist, simply comment out the related addcolumn in the Up() method above.